# Error: Could not find or load main class while trying to run spark from eclipse(scala ide 4.3)

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

i have build the project using sbt and imported into eclipse . while trying to execute from run configuration i cannot find my main class and on running the application its prompted with the following error : could not find the main class.i have installed spark-hadoop version 1.4 and scala version 2.10.6 in the local machine also changed the scala compiler version to 2.10.6 in scala ide . The same error is produced while trying build spark from eclipse using maven . Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

Check if Your main class in on build path.

Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source tab

If not add appropriate folder(s).

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder where classes are generated to build path -> configure build path -> java build path -> source -> "Default Output Folder" text box.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have .scala files included in compilation path. 
Even if you have the source folder included, it may be possible that .scala files are not being picked up.

The following might help, I was facing the same issue and it solved the problem for me:

```
build path -> configure build path -> java build path -> source -> add **/*.scala in the Included section.
```